Pyspark SQL understanding append and overwrite without a primary key
I have a notebook that reads many parquet files in /source/Year=x/Month=y/Day=z, which is partitioned by the year, month, and day of the date the file was loaded (this is important, it is NOT the date of any particular field in the data itself).  There's a recordTimestamp field that is generally the same as the day before the load date - /source is generated elsewhere each day from an extract.  But the recordTimestamp could actually be anything, such as a year old record that was previously not included for whatever reason.
My notebook loads these source files, runs (ideally) daily.  It writes data to /destination/Year=x/Month=y/Day=z, and that is partitioned by the recordTimestamp in the data (not the date the /source file was loaded).
For now the /destination is written using a full overwrite.  It's getting expensive obviously, and I think we need to move to an append operation.  I understand the syntax and such, but I do not understand what's happening under the hood.  My background is very SQL-heavy.  From a logic perspective in SQL this is a MERGE operation based on a primary key or something.  From my research it doesn't seem like that SQL analogy is the right mentality.
The /source data has no primary key, so my SQL logic goes out the window.  There's no combination of fields that is 100% bulletproof unique.
Currently this is all parquet, but I'm open to delta if that helps.
So my question is - how can I append only new records, keeping them in the correct /destination partitions, with no PK of any kind?
Per year I'm dealing with about a billion records, and it's WIDE - 120 fields or so.
All of this lives on Azure Synapse and ADLS2

i think you have to put in more sample example data. But from what i understand Delta table will be better for you as you may also be able to UPSERT the records (obviously based on a PK) but if you dont have to, create a new file on each write with Delta records and dedup that data on the read

please add details around the data volume such volume size of a particular folder and your current storage technology such as AWS S3 or any particular

I think you have to track which source partitions have been processed manually. As long as you never process a source partition twice, appending to the target partitions should be fine (assuming there are no duplicates in the source).

@AnandVidvat added at the bottom of the post, thanks
